# Public IP address in Alibaba Cloud instance

Tags: cloud-computing

Is it possible to assign public IP address to an instance in Alibaba Cloud that would be visible after running

```
ifconfig
```

And not assigned via NAT. Need this for provisioning K8s cluster and it doesn't work with NAT IP-addresses.

Comment: Based on https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/32321.htm, they wouldn't be visible by running `ifconfig`, but I'm not sure why that would be a benefit?

Answer (score 0):

It is sure you could choose independently public IP on Alibaba Cloud, when you create ECS, on the networking part, you would choose bind resources to EIP.

the detail guide and samples as below:

https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/72125.htm?spm=5176.ecsbuyv3.bandwidth.3.244a1594rWg3Y7

Answer (score -2):

All Alibaba Cloud ECS instances come with a public/internet IPv4 Address address that you can connect to remotely using SSH or any other client that supports the protocol.

You can check the public IP address on the Alibaba Cloud console and it should be listed along the ECS instances list.